# The simplest way to generate a shop without orders and payments using spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

I want to make an online catalogue like application for some stores in a shopping center so each shop can login to system and add/edit products for their shops. I'm forced to use ruby on rails.
After some searching I found spree!

But I didn't find any option to disable orders, payments, shipping and etc which are useless in a catalogue. Here are my questions:

Is spree a good starting point for my application? if not, can you give me some other open source projects?

How can I disable Payments and other useless options for my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to use Spree for this. Just because it includes the "piece" you want for your own puzzle doesn't mean it is designed to operate independently of Spree. It is incredibly easy using rails to create a simple "read only" catalog that other users can update and maintain. I would suggest spending some time to get familiar with rails and its pros and cons pertinent to your use case.

Spree is designed to be a developer orientated e-commerce platform. It has a 'catalog' as you would describe it as a requirement for its primary purpose: The exchange of goods for money. This is not your use case so spree will not help you with your goals.